# CSS/Html: Separate background from divs

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to build a webpage with two parts, but three backgrounds.

The first part is the page header, with it's own background.

The second part I have a problem with. It's the content part, and it consists of a "top" background, and a "body" background. The top background is a single image, the body background is another image, repeating itself (tiled) to the end of the page.

The problem is that the division between top and body, is only for the background. The content is continous and the same image starts in the top part, and continues down to the body part.

[image]

Originally, I tried using:

```
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="content-top">...</div> 
<div class="content-body">...</div>
```

but the problem is that then I couldn't put stuff that will span both the `.content-top` div and the `.content-body` div. If I put a larger component in the `.content-top` div it will push down the `.content-body` div, including the background, leaving a hole in the middle.

How can this be done?

**Edit**: Here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem - https://jsfiddle.net/nj13ktms/6/

Comment: Please can you share the fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nj13ktms/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two backgrounds in the same container:

```
.content-top {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/VcvKC2F.jpg) no-repeat center top, url(http://i.imgur.com/FLEHfrY.jpg) repeat-y center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3nqry4x/

(Note: I removed the second DIV and put its contents into the first one)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you can have two backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'background-image'

```css
.section  {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100px;
}

.top {
background-image: url("https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg");
}

.middle {
background-image: url("http://random-international.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/RR-home-img2.jpg");
}

.bottom {
background-image: url("http://www.chainimage.com/images/random-animals-animals-photo-8676039-fanpop.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="section top"></div>
<div class="section middle"></div>
<div class="section bottom"></div>
```

Comment: That wasn't the question, I know how to create 3 sections with 3 backgrounds. What I need is to create 2 sections with 3 background, so that the backgrounds are separate from the sections.

Comment: You really should edit your question then. Is this what you want? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp